# flutter: A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't understand how to lead to one type
my function:

```
Future<String> getToken(String login) async {
    final data = await (select(authInfos)
          ..where((tbl) => tbl.login.equals(login)))
        .getSingle();
    return data.token;
  }
```

row with error:

```
String token = myDatabase.authInfosDao.getToken(login);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functions that returns a future result you will need to put `await` on calling it to ensure that the variable will get the return of the said function.

Here's the Syntax:

```
String token = await myDatabase.authInfosDao.getToken(login);
```

**Update:**

```
Future<void> initState() async {
    // TODO: implement initState
    String token = await myDatabase.authInfosDao.getToken(login);
    super.initState();
}
```

Note: When using `await` expression it should be used on an `async` funtion.

Comment: I tried it this way and it gave me this error : "The await expression can only be used in an async function. Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*' "

Comment: Could you provide the code where you implement the call. Usually when you encounter this you just have to add the "async". For example on initState(), I'll edit the answer.